# Best ways to test a responsive website

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been tasked with creating a website (using mainly javascript & JQuery) that reads in a certain element from a website - e.g. the navigation bar - and test it to see how it react at different screen sizes.

My question is that is this a good approach? To test elements one at a time instead of just testing the responsiveness of the whole page? Wouldn't an element react differently to media query changes with other elements around it, rather than the element by itself?

Answer (score 1):

My vote will be to firefox default responsive tester. Use Ctrl+Shift+M to make the firefox screen responsive.

If you want to see the dimensions with name, go with google chrome, right-click, inspect element. There you will see a mobile icon. Click that.This will give you a dropdown of variety of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the good approach is to test the whole page.  But clearly there are cases when element testing is necessary, even disabling certain ones and check the rest together.  So the tool you're about to create actually makes sense; not good enough, tho.  But maybe you're better off with a Google Chrome element inspector and some "display:none"-s.

(Side note: [this is my own responsivity tester](http://deneskellner.com/reframe) and I never needed much more than this.  It aims for the typical bootstrap breakpoints; it has maybe twelve lines of code, it's just as complex as a screwdriver.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try it on native devices you should check out [www.browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com)

There is an extensions for your browser so that you can run local sites (localhost), on the emulated device.

30 min trial is free which is usually enough for a few tests.